# Need explanation of the ruby gem loading process. Not rails, just plain ruby. Some gems get loaded and others dont get loaded. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, capistrano

Ruby is so darn mysterious when it comes to using the gems! Where do these gems reside?? In java, you can have as many jars you want just include them in your CLASSPATH and your good to go. Ruby is a simpler language, but why do I need the headache of dealing with simple crap? Can anyone seriously finally explain how the gem loading process works? It seems like no one really knows why the heck do requiring some gems work, and requiring others doesn't even if you have gem installed them and they are in the gem list. Where is the authority in ruby on this site that can finally clarify the gem loading process.

I am tried of including 'rubygems' in my ruby scripts to prevent errors like `LoadError: no such file to load -- pony`

And even when I do require 'rubygems' in my scripts, it still gives LoadErrors. Even if the gem is in my gem list.

Comment: Are you using RVM or Rbenv to manage multiple rubies? How are you executing the script?

Comment: No need to shout man, keep cool ;)

Comment: Commentary on the "mysteriousness" of RubyGems is not required to ask a question. Just sayin'

Comment: btw, `gem env` will tell you the load paths for your gems

Comment: no RVM. just pure ruby. Charles, are you serious? Ruby is for non-engineers wanting to be hackers. There is a gem for everything. Wanna find the time? theres a gem for that.. What language allows this kind of garbage?

Comment: You misunderstood. StackOverflow is a place to ask questions and get answers. It is also a means to gather knowledge and understanding on topics and find further documentation on those topics. It is not a place to take up the majority of your question's text with commentary. That is better discussed in SO's chat. In regards to your specific situation, you may have set up Ruby or RubyGems incorrectly. I have been coding Ruby (not Rails) for 3 years and have never run into this issue.

Comment: If you want to ask a question, ask a question. If you want to write a blog post, write a blog post. Please don't mix the two.

Comment: There should be down arrows for all your comments. You dont know anything about pure ruby and are just crazy rails fanatics!

Comment: Its clear that you are frustrated, and we all get frustrated with programming things. It's just the nature of working with something that is very complicated. But, attacking people who are offering you free help is not a healthy axiom to live by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com) to manage Gems in your project (you will have a `Gemfile` at the root directory of the project), be sure to run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: its not rails! its ruby!! Im writing ruby scripts!

Comment: Bundler is not directly related to Rails. You can use it in other projects, too. Rails simply happens to use Bundler for Gem management.

Comment: How can I use bundler in other projects? Please edit your response accordingly. I am working with straight ruby scripts and using irb to test

Comment: Check the link i posted, it's everything there. I won't edit my post just to repeat everything on the bundler page.

Comment: The link has absolutely nothing to do with using pure ruby scripts. Its all about using it with rails.. Its as if ruby was created for rails.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the place to tell people what they know and what they don't or to start a religious war. If you don't like the community stop offending people and try posing your poorly formulated questions sprikled with hate elsewhere. Good luck.

Comment: You guys get offended by everything. If its a question about an environment setup, ruby advocates get flummoxed!

Comment: I see you accepted my answer. So did it actually solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

requiring rubygems just loads rubygems itself (and isn't required in ruby 1.9 and above)

You need to actually load each gem individually via `require`.

If you use bundler, then you can optionally have bundle auto require everything from your Gemfile

Comment: That may well do the trick! +1 for thinking outside the box ;)